# 777 permission for folder to upload files

Tags: php

I want to know that if we set the 777 permission on a folder to upload filed, do we need to set the permission of internal folders as well or it will work inside the external folder for which we have set the permission
exp.
images/newfolder
if we set the permission of images, newfolder will allow uploading files automatically or not?

Comment: Also 777 is not a good idea. It is an open door to everybody

Comment: `755` is probably your best shot, but set its owner to the web user in order to correctly write it when uploading. Even `700` should be fine. For **your files**, however, a `644` (or `600`) should do the work.

Comment: The execute/search bit for a folder is useful? Also get the `umask` correct

Comment: @EdHeal probably. Do a `chmod -x folder/` and then `cd folder/`. Without execute bit it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is no. Setting 777 permissions on a folder does not guarantee that all sub folders are also having the permission 777. Unless you do that recursively. So check which OS you use and do that recursively. I use linux (Ubuntu) and I can do this

`sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/dir/`

Comment: `sudo` is not really necessary there. You could create a folder with your own username and set its permissions to `777`.